# Perl Tk TixGrid Error - "tixGrid: mappedWindows not NULL"

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

Getting this error using TixGrid in Perl Tk:

**tixGrid: mappedWindows not NULL**

**Abort (core dumped)**

TixGrid is version 4.010.

Basically what is happening is TixGrid is storing all mapped windows in mappedWindows, which I am assuming is a linked list based on some searches I did. When destroying the window, whether it is the TixGrid widget or the main window, the program crashes and gives this error. My guess is it is because TixGrid requires mappedWindows to be NULL in order to close correctly, but a bug in the code forgot to make it NULL when destroying the widget or main window.

I have been unable to find a fix online. I am worried that if I continue without finding a fix this may come back to bite me in the ass bigtime in a few weeks.

Anyone know a fix or workaround for this?

Here is some simple code I made just to test TixGrid which alerted me to the error. It comes up whenever you close the main window or hit the "Close" button. In this code it is the main window being destroyed by the close button, but it gives the error if you destroy the TixGrid widget as well.

```html
#!usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Tk;
use Tk::TixGrid;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;

my $grid = $mw->Scrolled(
'TixGrid',
-background  => "white"
)->pack;


my $button = $mw->Button(
-text=>  => "Close",
-command => sub{$mw->destroy}
)->pack;

&packrow(0);

MainLoop;


sub packrow{
my $row = $_[0];
my $cb_state;

my $cb = $grid->Checkbutton(
-text   => "Test",
-variable  => \$cb_state,
-background  => "white",
-activebackground => "white"
);



$grid->set($row,0, -itemtype=> 'window', -widget=> $cb,);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is thinking of using `Tk::TixGrid` because they cannot get `Tk::Table` to delete whole rows at a time, and are having issues with `Tk::TixGrid` I would suggest using `Tk::Table` and implementing the row deletion algorithm implemented here:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136398/perl-tk-need-table-that-can-insert-other-widgets-and-delete-whole-rows`